# ngTable doesn't update data on making AJAX call in AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngTable to show the data. First time when I click a button, it makes an AJAX call and shows the data. After that, upon clicking some buttons, it makes an AJAX call, it gets new data but it doesn't get updated in table.

This is my controller code:

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-point").on("click", function (hourly_datapoint) {
            console.log("hourly_datapoint",hourly_datapoint);
            $http.post('/api/hostlevel', hourly_datapoint).
              success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);

                var data = data[0].data[0][hourly_datapoint.time];
                console.log(data);

                $scope.$watch('data', function () {
                  $scope.tableParams.settings().$scope = $scope;
                  $scope.tableParams.reload();
                });

                $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                  page: 1,            // show first page
                  count: 10           // count per page
                }, {
                  total: data.length, // length of data
                  getData: function($defer, params) {
                    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                  }
                });
              }).
              error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
              });
          });
        }
```

And this is the view code:

```
<div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" ng-show="$data.length >0">
      <tr ng-repeat="hostlevel in $data">
        <td data-title="'Messages Received'">{{hostlevel["in"]}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Messages Processed'">{{hostlevel["out"]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

How do I dynamically update the table content? Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Where do you assign the request data to $scope.$data?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to angularJS world. I followed the following: http://plnkr.co/edit/ISa4xg?p=info and assigned the data variable. Am I missing something here?